# Normal Distribution mean and standard deviation unknown

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, standard-deviation, means

The problem is this:
The daily rainfall in a city is normally distributed with mean μ mm and standard deviation σ mm. The rainfall on one day is independent of the rainfall on any other day. On a randomly selected day, there is a 5% chance that the rainfall is more than 10.2 mm. In a randomly selected seven-day week, there is a probability of 0.025 that the mean daily rainfall is less than 6.1 mm. Find the values of μ and σ.

I have been able to develop expressions for the Z-scores easily enough but have difficulty with the next steps in solving for $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

The textbook gives the answers as $\mu$=7.37 and $\sigma$=1.72

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: The chance of a measurement exceeding $\mu + \sigma$ is about 16%; the chance of a measurement exceeding $\mu  + 2 \cdot \sigma$ is about 2.5%. One can similarly calculate some number $\delta$ between one and two so that the chance of a measurement exceeding $\mu + \delta \cdot \sigma$ is 5%. This gives an equation $ \mu + \delta \cdot \sigma = 10.2 mm$ and is half the solution to your problem.

Comment: For the second half: how is the average over seven measurements distributed, given that all single measurements are independently normally distributed with $\mu, \sigma$ as parameters?

Comment: I would assume normally distributed but I only have the question info to go on. The question was taken from a textbook section on sampling distributions.

Answer (score 0):

@AlexanderGeldhof has given useful clues toward the solution in Comments. This is a
slightly more detailed presentation.

First, you know that rainfall on a randomly chosen day is 
$X \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma).$ 
Second, you know that the average rainfall during a randomly
chosen week is $\bar X \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma/\sqrt{7}).$

Then you are given
$$0.05 = P(X > 10.2) = P\left(Z = \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} > \frac{10.2-\mu}{\sigma}\right),$$
where $Z$ is standard normal. Thus $\frac{10.2-\mu}{\sigma} = 1.645,$ from
the following computation in R, where `qnorm` is the quantile function (inverse CDF) of a standard normal distribution. You can also find the value 1.645 using printed normal CDF tables.

```
qnorm(.95)
[1] 1.644854
```

Moreover, you are given
$$.025 = P(\bar X < 6.1) = P\left(Z = \frac{\bar X - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{7}} < \frac{6.1 - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{7}}\right),$$
so that $\frac{6.1 - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{7}} = -1.96.$

```
qnorm(.025)
[1] -1.959964
```

Now you have two equations in the two unknowns $\mu$ and $\sigma,$ which you
can solve to get numerical values. Except (possibly) for minor rounding discrepancies, your solutions should match the answers provided.

*Note:* In general, if any two quantiles of a normal distribution are
provided, then they may be used to find its mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma.$

Comment: Much appreciated!